# Javascript - call function from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `javascript` files:

```
//keystrokes.js
function KeyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 13 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
        alert("Ctrl+ent");
        dragTest;
      }
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```

and

```
//draggable.js
window.dragTest = function(){console.log('from draggable')};
```

and they are both include in `index.html`:

```
...
<script src="js/dragging.js"></script>
    <script src="js/keystrokes.js"></script>...
```

I want to call `dragTest` from `draggable.js` when I hit CTRL+ENTER. It did call alert function but never show anything at console. How can I go about to get this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parentheses to call functions.

```
dragTest();
```